# Calling multiple functions only if one gets executed with out any errors

Tags: python

I have written some user defined functions, which I want to call in such a way that only if `fun_a()` is executed properly without any errors, 
then `fun_b()` should be executed.

On the other hand, if any error happened, the script should be terminated and return an error message that the script broke at `fun_a()`.

Comment: Define "any errors". If `fun_a` raises an exception then the program will stop anyway. So what do you mean by "any errors" exactly?

Comment: You can write `fun_b()` after `fun_a()` from the moment `fun_a()` raises an Exception, it will stop and report that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done with a `try-except-else` block

```
try:
    fun_a():
except Exception as e:
    print "An error has occurred: {}".format(e)
else:
    fun_b()
```

So if you want to do this with more than two functions, you can loop through them and break the loop if one raises an error.

```
functions = [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c]

for function in functions:
    try:
        function()
    except Exception as e:
        print "An error has occurred while running {0}: {1}".format(function, e)
        break
```

As mentioned in the comments, it might be better to just let the error stop the program anyway, instead of handling it and manually stopping the program.

Comment: Didn't know about the `else`, nice job

Comment: @JoeIddon [Look at this](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/the-possibly-forgotten-optional-else-in-python-try-statement)

Comment: How would you do it if the "multiple" functions were more than just two?

Comment: Your second code block runs each of the middle functions (that is, all but the first and last) twice. You should probably just call them all inside a single `try` statement (or even without the `try`/`except`, and just let the exception stop the program).

Comment: @Blckknght I'm so dumb. I've fixed the answer and added your idea to the answer as a note.

Answer (score -1):

Run this:

```
try:

    fun_a():
except Exception, BaseException as e:
    print(f'An error has occurred: {f}')
else:
    fun_b()
```

Comment: this code does not work. there is an unexpected colon after `fun_a()`, and you can't `except Exception, BaseException as e`. And what is `f'An error has occurred: {f}` supposed to do?